# Ruby: Severe performance hit when using 'puts'

Tags: ruby, performance

In our Ruby web scraper, when using the 'puts' command for troubleshooting the method takes several minutes longer to complete compared to when nothing is outputted into the console. This is despite only outputting a couple of hundred (less than a thousand) strings. I understand that a method takes longer to complete if it has a larger quantity of tasks to complete, but it feels a bit absurd for the length to essentially double. Especially when you take into account that a lot of time (both when using puts and not using puts) is just waiting to not get locked out after a fetch request.

The 'puts' command is used in a loop but the number of outputs are only in the hundreds.

Is it supposed to be this way? If so, why?

Comment: Printing strings should be blazing fast. Maybe the objects you're printing are not strings and it's their `to_s` method which takes so long?

Comment: @Stefan isn't it `inspect` actually?

Comment: We use mechanize to look through the individual webpages but the only thing we print out is the URL to the page. How does the speed at which `to_s` completes vary depending on the object?

We use the `.uri` parser in mechanize to get the links.

Comment: @JQuist can you show some code? Preferably a [mcve]

Comment: @MarekLipka `p` calls `inspect` whereas `puts` calls `to_s`

Comment: "How does the speed at which to_s completes vary depending on the object?" Simple objects like numbers are relatively straight forward to cast. Then you have arrays and hashes which are slightly more complex and then you have complex objects like a Nokogiri XML document where `to_s` has to convert the whole document tree to a XML string.

Comment: What happens when you redirect the output of the program to a file? What happens when you redirect to `/dev/null`? What measurements do you have that prove that it is Ruby being slow and not the console?

Comment: "Severe performance hit" requires a code sample to reproduce the issue. Vague explanations are not helpful. Voted to close as the question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JQuist I've hit the same issue in the past, and had figure it had something to do with the thing install (Specific build pack on heroku, which we worked with) on my server and specifically related to something in the range of selenium, web drivers, scraping area.. Never figure out what caused the issue. But we remove all Puts from our code and move onto logging into our database, probably any external logger would work!